# Using a OpenfileDialog to open and import a tab delimited text file into an MS Access database in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, import, openfiledialog, csv

Progress has been made and I am no longer receiving the out of bounds error. I am now getting the message box that I defined in the code that tells the user that the file has been uploaded (image shown below). However when I check the database or refresh the dataset the new data isn't there. I feel as though it is something to do with the connection statement in the try catch but I'm not certain. Any suggestions?

[image: Uploaded file message box]

```
private void newFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream myStream = null;

            ofd.Title = "Select Text File";
            ofd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            ofd.Filter = "Text Files (.txt) |*.txt";
            ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if ((myStream = ofd.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(myStream);
                        string text = reader.ReadLine(); //code to read each line word by word and divide it up//
                        string[] row = text.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        foreach (string c in row)
                        {
                            string[] rejects = c.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                            string Column1 = rejects[0];
                            string Column2 = rejects[1];
                            string Column3 = rejects[2];
                            string Column4 = rejects[3];
                            string Column5 = rejects[4];
                            string Column6 = rejects[5];
                            string Column7 = rejects[6];
                            string Column8 = rejects[7];
                            string Column9 = rejects[8];
                            string Column10 = rejects[9];
                            string Column11 = rejects[10];
                            string Column12 = rejects[11];
                            string Column13 = rejects[12];
                            string Column14 = rejects[13];
                            string Column15 = rejects[14];
                            string Column16 = rejects[15];
                            string Column17 = rejects[16];
                            string Column18 = rejects[17];
                            string Column19 = rejects[18];
                            string Column20 = rejects[19];
                            string Column21 = rejects[20];
                            string Column22 = rejects[21];
                            string Column23 = rejects[22];
                            string Column24 = rejects[23];
                            string Column25 = rejects[24];
                            string Column26 = rejects[25];
                            string Column27 = rejects[26];
                            string Column28 = rejects[27];
                            string Column29 = rejects[28];
                            string Column30 = rejects[29];

                            try
                            {
                                string Column31 = "1";
                                string Insert = "INSERT INTO tblReject_test (sop_instance_uid, study_instance_uid, accession_number, patient_id, patient_name, date_of_birth, sex, study_date, study_time, mpm_code, body_part_examined, ank_menu_name, kanji_menu_name, s_value, l_value, ip_number, fcr_image_id, technologist, requesting_department, Kanji_requesting_department, size_code, film_mark1, film_mark2, status, technologist_code, ip_number2, reject_category, reject_comment, code, reject_image, department_id) VALUES ('" + Column1 + "," + Column2 + "," + Column3 + "," + Column4 + "," + Column5 + "," + Column6 + "," + Column7 + "," + Column8 + "," + Column9 + "," + Column10 + "," + Column11 + "," + Column12 + "," + Column13 + "," + Column14 + "," + Column15 + "," + Column16 + "," + Column17 + "," + Column18 + "," + Column19 + "," + Column20 + "," + Column21 + "," + Column22 + "," + Column23 + "," + Column24 + "," + Column25 + "," + Column26 + "," + Column27 + "," + Column28 + "," + Column29 + "," + Column30 + "," + Column31 + "')";

                                //database connection to execute insert command
                                string connectiontring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdb";
                                DataConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectiontring);
                                DataConnection.Open();
                                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Insert, DataConnection);

                                database1DataSet.tblReject_test.Clear();
                                this.tblReject_testTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.tblReject_test);

                                MessageBox.Show("File has been uploaded.");
                                DataConnection.Close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You assume that your line is splittable in 31 elements. But what if a single line has less  that 31 elements? None checks this condition and this gives the _out of range_ exception

Answer (score 0):

Probably when you splits `c` string, the resulting array `rejects` have less than 31 elements.

Perhaps there is an empty line at the end of the array "row".

Use better the overload `Split(char[], StringSplitOptions)`:

```
string[] row = text.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] rejects = c.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You can add an `if` statement checking the length of the array before the query:

```
string[] row = text.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string c in row)
{
    string[] rejects = c.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (rejects.Length > 30)
    {
        string Column1 = rejects[0];
        string Column2 = rejects[1];
        string Column3 = rejects[2];
        string Column4 = rejects[3];
        string Column5 = rejects[4];
        string Column6 = rejects[5];
        string Column7 = rejects[6];
        string Column8 = rejects[7];
        string Column9 = rejects[8];
        string Column10 = rejects[9];
        string Column11 = rejects[10];
        string Column12 = rejects[11];
        string Column13 = rejects[12];
        string Column14 = rejects[13];
        string Column15 = rejects[14];
        string Column16 = rejects[15];
        string Column17 = rejects[16];
        string Column18 = rejects[17];
        string Column19 = rejects[18];
        string Column20 = rejects[19];
        string Column21 = rejects[20];
        string Column22 = rejects[21];
        string Column23 = rejects[22];
        string Column24 = rejects[23];
        string Column25 = rejects[24];
        string Column26 = rejects[25];
        string Column27 = rejects[26];
        string Column28 = rejects[27];
        string Column29 = rejects[28];
        string Column30 = rejects[29];
        string Column31 = rejects[30];

        string Insert = "INSERT INTO tblReject_test (sop_instance_uid, study_instance_uid, accession_number, patient_id, patient_name, date_of_birth, sex, study_date, study_time, mpm_code, body_part_examined, ank_menu_name, kanji_menu_name, s_value, l_value, ip_number, fcr_image_id, technologist, requesting_department, Kanji_requesting_department, size_code, film_mark1, film_mark2, status, technologist_code, ip_number2, reject_category, reject_comment, code, reject_image, department_id) VALUES ('" + Column1 + "," + Column2 + "," + Column3 + "," + Column4 + "," + Column5 + "," + Column6 + "," + Column7 + "," + Column8 + "," + Column9 + "," + Column10 + "," + Column11 + "," + Column12 + "," + Column13 + "," + Column14 + "," + Column15 + "," + Column16 + "," + Column17 + "," + Column18 + "," + Column19 + "," + Column20 + "," + Column21 + "," + Column22 + "," + Column23 + "," + Column24 + "," + Column25 + "," + Column26 + "," + Column27 + "," + Column28 + "," + Column29 + "," + Column30 + "," + Column31 + "')";
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

In the updated code, you are creating the command `cmd`, but you have not executed. You need to call `ExecuteNonQuery()` method:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Insert, DataConnection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Using your code I no longer get the error. I decided to add another message box under the INSERT statement to ensure that the code was actually doing something and unfortunately the message box did not appear, however I received no errors. But the data has not been inserted into the database either.

Updated code in post.

Comment: @iiAaronXiX: I updated my answer, but the problem is that you aren't running the command.